# Multiple SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) database instances on one machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

i want to configured the configuration file to use more than one MSDB database, which are stored in separated database instances in Stored packages of SSIS database. if any body knows let me know ?
write in steps how to do..?

Regards.
kumar

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml:
[Configuring the Integration Services Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137789%28SQL.90%29.aspx)